# Upated class attribute not getting reflected in multiprocessing function

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, attributes

I have a Python 3.6.6 multiprocessing function running on windows

```
import multiprocessing as mp

class Foo:
    def __new__(cls):
        return None
    name = 'apple'

    @staticmethod
    def worker():
        print(f'Inside worker => {Foo.name}')

    @staticmethod
    def caller():
        for _ in range(3):
            p = mp.Process(target=Foo.worker)
            p.start()
            p.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Foo.name ='ball'
    Foo.caller() # worker prints apple
    Foo.worker() # prints ball
```

As per my understanding, in the function `worker` the values of class attribute `name` should  `ball` but actually it's `apple`.

I looked for an explanation for this but can't find any. Thanks in advance.

Comment: different processes *do not share state*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program has 4 processes: 1 main and 3 children. You modify the class attribute in your `main` process but any newly spawned process will load the class again, using the values in the class definition.

The main difference between threads and processes is shared memory. If you use `Thread`s instead of `Process`es you will see that it will use the modified class definition:

```
p = threading.Thread(target=Foo.worker)
```

Comment: So it means, Ineed to do the assignment again in the spawned process(worker)

Comment: Either that, or use threads if you need to share state.

Comment: Thanks, BTW, using multiprocessing because I need out of process execution. So cant go with thread.

Comment: There are methods for sharing state between processes too. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes